# Cannot get Authlogic working under Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, authlogic

**spec_helper.rb** [source](https://bitbucket.org/andey/bestofama/src/89031511e3e3/spec/spec_helper.rb?at=stackoverflow)

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'authlogic/test_case' # include at the top of test_helper.rb
include Authlogic::TestCase
```

**test_spec.rb** [source](https://bitbucket.org/andey/bestofama/src/89031511e3e3/spec/requests/test_spec.rb?at=stackoverflow)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Stackoverflow" do
  describe "GET /test" do
    it "is logged in #1" do
      activate_authlogic
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      UserSession.create(user)
      get page_path('test')
      response.body.should include('YES')
    end

    it "is logged in #2" do
      activate_authlogic
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      UserSession.find
      get page_path('test')
      response.body.should include('YES')
    end
  end
end
```

**test.html.erb** [source](https://bitbucket.org/andey/bestofama/src/89031511e3e3/app/views/pages/test.html.erb?at=stackoverflow)

```
<% if current_user %>
    YES LOGGED IN
<% else %>
    NOT LOGGED IN
<% end %>
```

**Screenshot it working my browser**

- Chrome is logged in
- Opera is logged out

[image: screenshot]

### The Problem

Both my tests fail. Authlogic doesn't seem to create / find the session. My view should "YES LOGGED IN". If I haven't shown something relevant, you may look at my complete [source code](https://bitbucket.org/andey/bestofama/src/89031511e3e33b6caadcbd57760edf339c7f984f/?at=stackoverflow)

Comment: The source code you linked to isn't runnable (missing spec folder and database.yml) -- any chance you could create a repo that I could easily clone and run?

Comment: PG test db backup: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4154410/bestofama/brestofama.backup, everything zipped up: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4154410/bestofama/bestofama.tar.bz2 . The simple example with authlogic that fails is requests/pages_spec

Comment: OK, I wasn't able to get all the way --- but one thing: your user created by the factory is not active. So the UserSession.create fails with this message: "Your session is invalid and has the following errors: Your account is not active". That doesn't solve the problem completely, but it might move you further down the road.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely put me in the right direction. That being fixed, still getting some odd message: <Authlogic::Session::Validation::Errors:0x0000000609e8a8 @base=#<UserSession: {:unauthorized_record=>"<protected>"}>, @messages={}> . Which is very weird, because when I create my user, Authlogic puts in a persistent token in to the user record.